# Should I add additional unit tests for this helper method that simply aids in refactoring of code?

Tags: c#, testing

I have a method:

```
public static void AddPersonToPeopleList(List<PersonModel> people, PersonModel person)
        {
            CheckWhiteSpace(person.FirstName, "FirstName");
            CheckWhiteSpace(person.LastName, "LastName");

            people.Add(person);
        }
```

That calls the helper methdod:

```
public static void CheckWhiteSpace(string name, string paramName) {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("You passed in an invalid parameter", paramName);
            }
        }
```

Which simply checks for null or white space in my string with the parameter name, and throws an exception if it does.

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("Mick", "", "LastName")]
        [InlineData("", "Adams", "FirstName")]
        public void AddPersonToPeopleList_ShouldFail(string firstName, string lastName, string param)
        {
            PersonModel newPerson = new PersonModel { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
            List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();

            Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(param, () => DataAccess.AddPersonToPeopleList(people, newPerson));
        }
```

My test is designed to simply make sure an exception is thrown if either the first name or second name is empty.

My question is whether I need to also make a test for the helper method I used (CheckWhiteSpace) or whether the test I've made takes care of testing the functionality of that helper method and my original method?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your intentions with the `CheckWhiteSpace` method:

- If `CheckWhiteSpace` is intended to become a reusable library function, placed in a class different from the one where `AddPersonToPeopleList` belongs to, then a unit test for it makes sense. The fact `CheckWhiteSpace` is public may be an indicator for this.
- If `CheckWhiteSpace` is currently not reused anywhere else, and you are not sure if it will ever be, then it should (currently) stay in the class where `AddPersonToPeopleList` "lives", and it should be made private. In this case, no additional unit test will be required.

Note it is an implementation detail of `AddPersonToPeopleList` that it uses `CheckWhiteSpace` internally, and implementation details may be subject to change. Furthermore, if you start with `CheckWhiteSpace` as a private method, but later decide to make it reusable in public, then it is early enough to write a separate unit test for this method.

It is neither a good idea to

- write any tests for implementation details,
- nor to leave out any tests because of making assumptions about implementation details.

So think which of the mentioned categories fits best to your case, then you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you wrote the code so it needs a test.

If you are arguing that it's too trivial to test then its equally too trivial to require the extra function, bundle it in with where ever its called.

You are bound to have Prince or Madonna sign up to your service and then you will thank me for making your write this test!

Here's How I would code it: Notice I have removed the static and added an interface to reduce coupling and so that we can test multiple implementations and mock the DataAccess in other tests.

Also, the validation check is so trivial that we move it to a private method. (no need to test private methods) But if it was more complex you would make a IPersonValidator and inject it into the DataAccess component. In this case you would want to test IPersonValidator in the same way we are testing IDataAccess here

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public List<Person> GetPeople() 
    {
        //return all the people
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        if(!validatePerson(p))
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid person");
        }
        //add to database
    }

    private bool validatePerson(Person p)
    {
        //validation code
    }
}

///tests
public void TestAddPerson()
{
    IDataAccess t = new DataAccess();
    var p = new Person() { Name="Madonna"});
    t.AddPerson(p);
    var actual = t.GetPeople();

    Assert.IsTrue(actual.Contains(p));
}
```

Comment: Do I need to test the code which already tested, through other method?

Comment: Agreed with @Ewan. Such a method makes so basic and common validation that it's likely the OP will reuse it eventually here and there. It's a matter of time and DRY. Implementing a unit test for so small functionality takes almost no time to code it and run it.

Comment: @fabio you are not testing the code, you are testing the method

Comment: @Ewan still :), do we need to test a method, which already tested through consumer of this method?

Comment: @Fabio, no you don't need to write new tests if that code is already properly covered by existing tests. Good automated testing practice is opposite to what Ewan says: you aren't testing methods (unless they are public APIs); you are testing functionality.

Comment: @fabio dont listen to david, you _do_ need to test this method. At the moment it might be fully covered at a higher level. But A. another class might use it in future and B. unit tests have value in addition to integration tests

Comment: @davidarno note, this is a public static method with no interface

Comment: And note that the good advice here is to make it private as it's currently just an implementation detail.

Comment: @DavidArno I would agree with that, also removing the static.  But that would be a different question

Comment: Removing the static would be a ridiculous thing to do. I often wonder whether you just troll us with these silly comments.

Comment: occasionally my comments might be provocative. but you should def remove the static. Of course we cant see the rest of the class, but we know that static is amost always bad. IPeopleContainer.AddPerson(person) is probably the way to go

Comment: @Fabio updated with example code

Comment: "*...but we know that static is amost always bad...*" No! Static is only bad if the function has side effects. If it has no side effects, then make it static. For some reason, you appear to have missed the memo on that one.

Comment: @DavidArno its also bad for a variety of other reasons. you should _never_ make a   function static simply to indicate lack of side effects. I mean just look at the example here which calls another static function!

Answer (score 2):

If you've been doing TDD properly, and this is method is something that you've created during refactoring, then ***no*** - as this is *already* covered by tests at the *appropriate* level of abstraction. Refactoring is rearranging the internals without changing the functionality - and without changing tests, that act as a safety net for you. You have to make a design decision though - decide (as a team) what constitutes internals vs what is the "surface area" that should be exposed to client code and to tests. Note that both clients and tests should be unaware of those internals. Otherwise you cannot refactor. Think of the test suite as being another client for the code being tested. If at some point you find that your high level design is not quite right or that functionality needs to change, then you have to change the tests as well, or add new ones - this is expected, but it is not refactoring.

Now, if you were making something like a library that other code will use, and this function was part of its API, then you would write a test for it directly, because it's at the "surface area" in this context, but you still wouldn't have your tests coupled to the internals of that library. This consideration is (roughly) along the same lines as Doc Brown's point about reuse.

That said, sometimes, when you are dealing with a difficult-to-understand piece of logic, or a complicated, finicky algorithm, but a lot of the intricacies of how it works constitutes internal detail in that particular level of abstraction, you may want to write tests that go into that detail, to help you get a handle on the problem. You have to somehow differentiate these tests from the other ones, though, as these aren't really a part of the test suite for the application/library - these are *for you*. Also, since this is internal detail, the code may be volatile, and so it may change relatively frequently in ways that will require these tests to change or make them outright obsolete. So you may not even check in these tests. You may decide to *delete* them once you're done (yes, this is allowed). Or if this peace of code is deemed to be of particular interest (at least for the time being), you may want to decide on a way to somehow differentiate these as white-box tests and check them in anyway, with the team having a mutual understanding that these are coupled to the internals (and that they may eventually need to be changed/replaced/deleted); it may be difficult to get everyone on the same page though, and your tools & pipeline may be setup in such a way as to make this awkward to implement. Again, if this code is of particular interest, and it turns out to be long-lived, another option to consider is to place it into a separate library/package, and then write these tests in that context - giving you proper isolation and separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

YAGNI principle:

It's up to looking at your own codebase to see whether you would need to use this validation elsewhere. If you do then it's reasonable to refactor out the method and then write a specific set of tests for it.

It looks like you are defining the helper method in the same class as your `AddPersonToPeopleList` class. If you want to explicitly test that functionality you can move it to a separate class or as an extension method of `string`.

If you decide to refactor, your code would could be something like:

```
public static class StringExtensions{
     public static void CheckWhiteSpace(this string name, string paramName){
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)
            throw new ArgumentException("You passed in an invalid parameter", paramName); 
     }
}
```

Called then as

```
person.FirstName.CheckWhiteSpace("FirstName")
```

Nice explanation here: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example:

First:
You need to add test cases for "FirstName" and "LastName" being `null` or white space `"   "`.

Second:
No, don't test logic which already tested through other tests.
If you are using `CheckWhiteSpace` somewhere else in your application, you probably are having tests which covers logic of `CheckWhiteSpace` as well.

Test separately logic which not fully tested through the consumers or not tested because of being mocked.